# How to copy the last class of element to another element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to copy the last class of each element to their parent li element in jQuery.

This is the current markup:

```
<nav class="menu-uber-main-menu-container">

    <ul class="menu">

        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page page_item">
            <a href="#" class="">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg menu-basket"></i>
                <span>Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>


        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page page_item">
            <a href="#" class="">
                <i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-lg menu-chart"></i>
                <span>About</span>
            </a>
        </li>


        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page page_item">
            <a href="#" class="">
                <i class="fa fa-truck fa-lg menu-truck"></i>
                <span>Blog</span>
            </a>
        </li>


    </ul>

</nav>
```

I want to copy and pass menu-basket, menu-chart, menu-truck to their parent li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page page_item"

The result should be:

```
    <ul class="menu">

        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page page_item menu-basket">
            <a href="#" class="">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg menu-basket"></i>
                <span>Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>


        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page page_item menu-chart">
            <a href="#" class="">
                <i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-lg menu-chart"></i>
                <span>About</span>
            </a>
        </li>


        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page page_item menu-truck">
            <a href="#" class="">
                <i class="fa fa-truck fa-lg menu-truck"></i>
                <span>Blog</span>
            </a>
        </li>


    </ul>

</nav>
```

The code for getting the last class of the element is this:

```
var lastClass = j('.menu-uber-main-menu-container > .menu > .menu-item > a > .fa').attr('class').split(' ').pop();
```

How to transfer each last class for each li element associatively?

Comment: Isn't getting the last class in the source a bit fragile?

Comment: Have you tried `.children()` or `.parent()` with `.addClass()`?

Comment: There's no such thing as the 'last class' on an element. They're stored in an arbitrary order, unless you want to start hacking around the `class` attribute value as a string - which isn't a great idea.

Comment: I agree with @Rory McCrossan. If I were you I would search for the term "menu" in the class that you're grabbing as opposed to just grabbing the last class of the element because I don't think that will be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `.each()`

```
$('.menu-uber-main-menu-container > .menu > li').each(function(){
    var className = $(this).find('.fa').attr('class').split(' ').pop();
    $(this).addClass(className);
});
```

Comment: Haha! Beat me to it